# What is the word for someone who checks ID cards before permitting entry?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for someone who checks ID cards (to verify a person's age) before permitting entry to an event or venue? Obviously, the word most commonly used in the context of a bar is "bouncer", but that seems very specific to bars/clubs and the word carries its own baggage.

What about in non-bar contexts? In San Francisco, the Sundance Kabuki is an upscale movie theater that serves alcohol for some screens, and they have a person checking IDs at a checkpoint. The word "bouncer" just sounds wrong to me in that context, but the only alternative I can come up with is "ID checker" (which sounds equally odd to me).

Is there a better word for the person who does this job?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doorman : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doorman

Answer (score 4):

Wordnet 3.0 says:

> `2`.  gatekeeper - someone who guards an entrance
>   doorman, hall porter, door guard, ostiary, porter, doorkeeper
>   commissionaire - a uniformed doorman
>   guard - a person who keeps watch over something or someone
>   night porter - a porter on duty during the night
>   ticket collector, ticket taker - someone who is paid to admit only those who have purchased tickets

Comment: [**Commissionaire**](http://www.onelook.com/?w=commissionaire&ls=a) is a very cool word. I will try to remember that word the next time I visit Wal-Mart.

Answer (score 2):

“Doorman” is good, but makes me (and Google) think you mean one of these guys:
[image]

In your scenario, I would describe that person and/or those working with him in similar functions collectively or individually as (the embodiment of) ***security.***

> “Have you seen any vehicles or other visitors in the vicinity in recent weeks?”
>
> [. . . .]
>
> “I'll check with **security** but I don't think so.”
>
> <sub>Source: [*The Whisper of Legends: An Inspector Green Mystery,*
> By Barbara Fradkin](http://books.google.com/books?id=MDB8Cgm-brEC&pg=PA318&lpg=PA318&dq=%22have+you+seen%22+%22check+with+security%22&source=bl&ots=8dV1s3je4k&sig=IHEaoCET4dIZ9tgpRJlKQHyRBvY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EuQ2VNGjNY2gyASn4YHIBQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22have%20you%20seen%22%20%22check%20with%20security%22&f=false)</sub>

Other examples of this usage [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have+you+seen%22+%22check+with+security%22).

It’s definitely a more general term, but in your context (or any of minimal specificity) a nice general term like this one can be very clear where an incorrectly specific term would sound strange.

Answer (score -2):

The word you are looking for is *bouncer*.